# EGit working / root directory

Tags: eclipse, git, salesforce, egit

I am trying to use EGit while doing Salesforce development. My problem is this. I don't like how EGit is pushing the folder structure. Its pushing like this:

```
project_name
    --.settings
    --Referenced Packages
    --src
        --classes
        --triggers
        package.xml
    .project
    salesforce.schema
```

I would ideally like the structure to look like this:

```
project_name
    --classes
    --triggers
    package.xml
```

I am nervous though to start moving things around and running git commands because I'm afraid it will break the GUI part of EGit which I need to work for team development. Any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably recommend just using [`.gitignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) file to exclude the other files, but if you really want to use `src` as the root of your project, you can try creating a second generic project in Eclipse that points directly to the `src` of your Force.com. To do this, go to **New** | **Project...** | **General** | **Project**, uncheck the **Use Default Location** checkbox and point the **Location** to the `src` directory of your Force.com project (e.g. `/Users/me/Workspaces/Force.com IDE/my-sfdc-project/src`). Now you can enable Git on the generic project. Both projects will point to the same files on disk (except the non-`src` directories), but the Force.com project will have the knowledge of your org and SFDC stuff, while the other will know about the source control.